# Strange emoji substitution on Apple Watch Simulator

Tags: ios, emoji, watchos-2

Strange emoji substitution on Apple Watch Simulator. Don't have any thoughts what is this :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect emoji mapping has been a bug in the watch simulator since Xcode 7.0. Not sure if a radar has been filed at this point (at least none that I can see on openradar).

First documented here: https://twitter.com/natashatherobot/status/657160166618628096